# RewriteCond - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using Opencart  with the SEO Friendly url's turned on.

That's made the .htaccess file look like this

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But I need to add in a folder exception that doesn't get rewritten, specifically /emailer

Looking around the web at answers I did the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(emailer|js|css)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

That makes /emailer/ work, but the other rewriting doesn't. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You just insert it before the main **RewriteRule**.

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(emailer|js|css) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1&request_uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

**Note:** It's not tested, but this should give you the idea how to do it.

**Later EDIT:**

I have tested my code and it didn't work. I have edited it and it works now, like this:

1. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` => if the request is not a real filename
2. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` => if the request is not a real directory
3. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(emailer|js|css) [NC]` => if there is not a directory/file in your root that starts with the words emailer/js/css
4. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)$ [NC]` => if the request does not end with an extension of the following ico/gif/jpg/jpeg/png/js/css

**Notes:**

- to test if you need a forward slash or not in your rewrite rule, append a query variable like i did in my modified example and print it (on the first line after the php open tag) in your index.php file like this:

  print_r($_GET['request_uri']);
  exit;

After you are done testing, remove the request_uri from htacces and index.php.

- Always escape the forward slash with a backslash, like this \ /

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. It's still rewriting /emailer. I tried putting it before and after the ico/gif, etc. Then I tried cancelling it down to RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/emailer/ [NC]. Still no luck.

Comment: I'm trying a lot of different combinations. It either crashes or rewrites the site. Here's what I have so far:

RewriteBase /  
  
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]  
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/emailer/?$  
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]